# Instagram JQuery change image size

Tags: jquery

Question regarding JQuery Instagram by Giovanni Cappellotto (https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram)

I wonder if it is possible somehow to extract bigger images from Instagram than just the 150x150px ones?

I tried following code, but that didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clientId = 'XXX';

  $('.instagram.tag').on('didLoadInstagram', didLoadInstagram);
  $('.instagram.tag').instagram({
    hash: 'tiger',
    image_size: 'high_resolution',
    count:1,
    clientId: clientId
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what Instagram's layout is, but if they don't offer a higher resolution image you can't get it. Basically look for a linked version that is larger. This ain't CSI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a *standard resolutions* image format using the `standard_resolution` key.

You should update the `didLoadInstagram` callback function to access images' `standard_resolution` url instead of `thumbnail` url.

Try this code to get more information about image's formats:

```
$('.instagram').on('didLoadInstagram', function(event, response) {
  response.data.forEach(function(photo) {
    console.log(photo.images);
  });
}).instagram({
  hash: 'love',
  clientId: 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE'
});
```

See an example response from Instagram API at: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search